# JSON dictionary to JSON object in SwiftyJSON

Tags: ios, swift, swifty-json

On login, my server returns a user json object if the login was successful. The structure of JSON is as follows:

```
{
    "user" = {
        [
            user info here
        ]
    }
}
```

As you can see, it returns the user data inside an array, and unfortunately, this cannot be changed.

I am trying to parse this data in the most efficient way possible with SwiftyJSON, but I've run into a problem. I want to check if there is a `"user"` key, and if so, parse the JSON object as JSON rather than a dictionary `[String: JSON]`. However, I can't figure out how to just cast `response["user"][0]` as a JSON object rather than a dictionary.

```
if let userInfo = response["user"][0].dictionary {

    let user = User.json_decode(userInfo) as! User

    User.setUser(user)
    success(user: user)

    return
}
else {
    failure(error: "Username or password was incorrect. Please try again")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this, `userinfo` is supposed to contain the dictionary

```
if let user = response["user"].array,  userinfo = user[0].dictionary {
  println(userinfo)
} else {
  failure(error: "Username or password was incorrect. Please try again")
}
```